# in org-mode, how to add code to the very end of exported HTML?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In org-mode's HTML export, I'd like to specify some HTML code—specific to one file, not a generic HTML postamble—for org to insert at the very END of the exported HTML page, AFTER the automatically-generated footnotes section.

How do I do this? And do I have to create a separate heading for this HTML code? I also don't want a blank dummy heading to appear in the table of contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the postamble of one org-file add the following lines at the bottom of the file:

```
# Local Variables:
# org-html-postamble: "test"
# End:
```

test stands here for the text you want to show in the postamble.
No blank dummy heading.

After you have added/changed the file local variables you need to reload your file or to run `M-x normal-mode` to re-read the file local variables.

At reloading you are asked whether you want to accept the file local settings. Answer the question with <kbd>!</kbd> to accept this kind of setting permanently.

To include a newline in the html source file you can use `\n`:

```
# Local Variables:
# org-html-postamble: "first line\nsecond line"
# End:
```

Alternatively, you can include newlines directly into the values of local variables. You just have to make sure that the prefix "# " is right:

```
# Local Variables:
# org-html-postamble: "first line
# second line
# third line"
# End:
```

Comment: Just put `\\n` as newline in.

Comment: You can include newlines directly in the value of a local variable. Maybe, that improves the clear representation of the value. I have edited the answer correspondingly.